# Creating test dependencies when using Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-2

While reading the docs for dagger 2 I cannot find an easy way to provide a dependency when building an app for testing. The only clue I've found is this:

> Dagger 2 doesn't support overrides. Modules that 
>   override for simple testing fakes can create 
>   a subclass of the module to emulate that behaviour. 
>   Modules that use overrides and rely on dependency injection 
>   should be decomposed so that the overridden modules are instead 
>   represented as a choice between two modules.

I don't understand how I would set up such a configuration on Android, anyone can explain?

Comment: What about https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html?

Answer (score 12):

This is currently impossible with Dagger 2 (as of v2.0.0) without some workarounds. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/110).

I've proposed [one workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939340/how-do-you-override-a-module-dependency-in-a-unit-test-with-dagger-2-0/29996385#29996385) but this requires changes to the production code.

In short:

- provide additional setter for `@Component` (e.g. in Android setter in `Application` class)
- test component must extend the production component

For more information please check both links. Hope this issue will be addressed in future versions of Dagger 2.

Comment: Great thanks! @tomrozb, that workaround should work for now, until a more elegant solution is available