# How can I swap test doubles at the scope of an Activity or a Fragment using Dagger 2?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, dagger-2, android-instrumentation

**EDIT: Watch out! I have deleted the old repository reffered to in this question. See my own answer to the question for a possible solution and feel free to improve it!**

I am refering to my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405839/dagger-2-dependency-injection-in-android-testcase). Now I came a little further. I am also refering to my two branches within my github Project:

- Experimental [branch no. 1] (repository deleted)
- Experimental [branch no. 2] (repository deleted)

In the old post I tried to swap components to test-components within an Instrumentation Test. This works now if I have an `ApplicationComponent`, being in singleton scope. But it does **not** work if I have an `ActivityComponent` with a self defined `@PerActivity` scope. The problem is **not** the scope but the swapping of the Component to the TestComponent.

My `ActivityComponent` has an `ActivityModule`:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    // TODO: Comment this out for switching back to the old approach
    void inject(MainFragment mainFragment);
    // TODO: Leave that for witching to the new approach
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

`ActivityModule` provides a `MainInteractor`

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    MainInteractor provideMainInteractor () {
        return new MainInteractor();
    }
}
```

My `TestActivityComponent` uses a `TestActivityModule`:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = TestActivityModule.class)
public interface TestActivityComponent extends ActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivityTest mainActivityTest);
}
```

`TestActvityModule` provides a `FakeInteractor` :

```
@Module
public class TestActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    MainInteractor provideMainInteractor () {
        return new FakeMainInteractor();
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` has a `getComponent()` method and a `setComponent()` method. With the latter you can swap the component to a test component within the Instrumentation Test. Here is the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Fragment currentFragment;
    private ActivityComponent activityComponent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeInjector();


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            currentFragment = new MainFragment();
            addFragment(R.id.fragmentContainer, currentFragment);
        }

    }

    private void initializeInjector() {
        Log.i(TAG, "injectDagger initializeInjector()");

        activityComponent = DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .activityModule(new ActivityModule())
                .build();
        activityComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(final Uri uri) {

    }

    ActivityComponent getActivityComponent() {
        return activityComponent;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public void setActivityComponent(ActivityComponent activityComponent) {
        Log.w(TAG, "injectDagger Only call this method to swap test doubles");
        this.activityComponent = activityComponent;
    }
}
```

As you see this activity uses a `MainFragment`. In `onCreate()` of the fragment the component is injected:

```
public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment implements MainView {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    @Inject
    MainPresenter mainPresenter;
    private View view;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "injectDagger onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // TODO: That approach works
//        ((AndroidApplication)((MainActivity) getActivity()).getApplication()).getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
        // TODO: This approach is NOT working, see MainActvityTest
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getActivityComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

And then in the test I swap the `ActivityComponent` with the `TestApplicationComponent`:

```
public class MainActivityTest{

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, true, false);

    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private TestActivityComponent mTestActivityComponent;

    // TODO: That approach works
//    private TestApplicationComponent mTestApplicationComponent;
//
//    private void initializeInjector() {
//        mTestApplicationComponent = DaggerTestApplicationComponent.builder()
//                .testApplicationModule(new TestApplicationModule(getApp()))
//                .build();
//
//        getApp().setApplicationComponent(mTestApplicationComponent);
//        mTestApplicationComponent.inject(this);
//    }

    // TODO: This approach does NOT work because mActivity.setActivityComponent() is called after MainInteractor has already been injected!
    private void initializeInjector() {
        mTestActivityComponent = DaggerTestActivityComponent.builder()
                .testActivityModule(new TestActivityModule())
                .build();

        mActivity.setActivityComponent(mTestActivityComponent);
        mTestActivityComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public AndroidApplication getApp() {
        return (AndroidApplication) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    }
    // TODO: That approach works

//    @Before
//    public void setUp() throws Exception {
//
//        initializeInjector();
//        mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
//        mActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
//    }

    // TODO: That approach does not works because mActivity.setActivityComponent() is called after MainInteractor has already been injected!
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mActivityRule.launchActivity(null);
        mActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        initializeInjector();
    }


    @Test
    public void testOnClick_Fake() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.edittext)).perform(typeText("John"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.textview_greeting)).check(matches(withText(containsString("Hello Fake"))));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnClick_Real() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.edittext)).perform(typeText("John"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.textview_greeting)).check(matches(withText(containsString("Hello John"))));
    }

}
```

The Activity test runs but the wrong `Component` is used. This is because activities and fragments `onCreate()` is run before the component is swapped.

As you can see I have an commented old approach were I bind an `ApplicationComponent` to the application class. This works because I can build the dependency before starting the activity. But now with the `ActivityComponent` I have to launch the activity before initializing the injector. Because otherwise I could not set

```
mActivity.setActivityComponent(mTestActivityComponent);
```

because `mActivity` would be null if would launch the activity after the initialization of the injector. (See `MainActivityTest`)

So how could I intercept the `MainActivity` and the `MainFragment` to use the `TestActivityComponent`?

Comment: You could turn this into a really good question by asking 'How can I swap test doubles at the scope of an Activity or a Fragment'. Most of the examples I have seen so far have instructions for swapping out the application-scoped component but nothing for injection sites further down.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found out by mixing some examples how to exchange an Activity-scoped component and a Fragment-scoped component. In this post I will show you how to do both. But I will describe in more detail how to swap a Fragment-scoped component during an InstrumentationTest. My total code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/unlimited101/SwappingTestDoubles). You can run the `MainFragmentTest` class but be aware that you have to set `de.xappo.presenterinjection.runner.AndroidApplicationJUnitRunner` as TestRunner in Android Studio.

Now I describe **shortly what to do to swap an Interactor by a Fake Interactor**. In the example I try to respect [clean architecture](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) as much as possible. But they may be some small things which break this architecture a bit. So feel free to improve.

So, let's start. At first you need an own JUnitRunner:

```
/**
 * Own JUnit runner for intercepting the ActivityComponent injection and swapping the
 * ActivityComponent with the TestActivityComponent
 */
public class AndroidApplicationJUnitRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader classLoader, String className, Context context)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.newApplication(classLoader, TestAndroidApplication.class.getName(), context);
    }

    @Override
    public Activity newActivity(ClassLoader classLoader, String className, Intent intent)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Activity activity = super.newActivity(classLoader, className, intent);
        return swapActivityGraph(activity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Activity swapActivityGraph(Activity activity) {
        if (!(activity instanceof HasComponent) || !TestActivityComponentHolder.hasComponentCreator()) {
            return activity;
        }

        ((HasComponent<ActivityComponent>) activity).
                setComponent(TestActivityComponentHolder.getComponent(activity));

        return activity;
    }
}
```

In `swapActivityGraph()` I create an alternative TestActivityGraph for the Activity before(!) the Activity is created when running the test. Then we have to create a `TestFragmentComponent`:

```
@PerFragment
@Component(modules = TestFragmentModule.class)
public interface TestFragmentComponent extends FragmentComponent{
    void inject(MainActivityTest mainActivityTest);

    void inject(MainFragmentTest mainFragmentTest);
}
```

This component lives in a Fragment-scope. It has a module:

```
@Module
public class TestFragmentModule {
    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    MainInteractor provideMainInteractor () {
        return new FakeMainInteractor();
    }
}
```

The original `FragmentModule` looks like that:

```
@Module
public class FragmentModule {
    @Provides
    @PerFragment
    MainInteractor provideMainInteractor () {
        return new MainInteractor();
    }
}
```

You see I use a `MainInteractor` and a `FakeMainInteractor`. They both look like that:

```
public class MainInteractor {
    private static final String TAG = "MainInteractor";

    public MainInteractor() {
        Log.i(TAG, "constructor");
    }

    public Person createPerson(final String name) {
        return new Person(name);
    }
}


public class FakeMainInteractor extends MainInteractor {
    private static final String TAG = "FakeMainInteractor";

    public FakeMainInteractor() {
        Log.i(TAG, "constructor");
    }

    public Person createPerson(final String name) {
        return new Person("Fake Person");
    }
}
```

Now we use a self-defined `FragmentTestRule` for testing the Fragment independent from the Activity which contains it in production:

```
public class FragmentTestRule<F extends Fragment> extends ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentTestRule";
    private final Class<F> mFragmentClass;
    private F mFragment;

    public FragmentTestRule(final Class<F> fragmentClass) {
        super(TestActivity.class, true, false);
        mFragmentClass = fragmentClass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched();
        try {
            mFragment = mFragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
        super.afterActivityLaunched();

        //Instantiate and insert the fragment into the container layout
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    public F getFragment() {
        return mFragment;
    }
}
```

That `TestActivity` is very simple:

```
public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        HasComponent<ActivityComponent> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        setContentView(frameLayout);
    }
}
```

But now how to swap the components? There are several small tricks to achieve that. At first we need a holder class for holding the `TestFragmentComponent`:

```
/**
 * Because neither the Activity nor the ActivityTest can hold the TestActivityComponent (due to
 * runtime order problems we need to hold it statically
 **/
public class TestFragmentComponentHolder {
    private static TestFragmentComponent sComponent;
    private static ComponentCreator sCreator;

    public interface ComponentCreator {
        TestFragmentComponent createComponent(Fragment fragment);
    }

    /**
     * Configures an ComponentCreator that is used to create an activity graph. Call that in @Before.
     *
     * @param creator The creator
     */
    public static void setCreator(ComponentCreator creator) {
        sCreator = creator;
    }

    /**
     * Releases the static instances of our creator and graph. Call that in @After.
     */
    public static void release() {
        sCreator = null;
        sComponent = null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@link TestFragmentComponent} or creates a new one using the registered {@link
     * ComponentCreator}
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if no creator has been registered before
     */
    @NonNull
    public static TestFragmentComponent getComponent(Fragment fragment) {
        if (sComponent == null) {
            checkRegistered(sCreator != null, "no creator registered");
            sComponent = sCreator.createComponent(fragment);
        }
        return sComponent;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if a custom activity component creator was configured for the current test run,
     * false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean hasComponentCreator() {
        return sCreator != null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a previously instantiated {@link TestFragmentComponent}.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if none has been instantiated
     */
    @NonNull
    public static TestFragmentComponent getComponent() {
        checkRegistered(sComponent != null, "no component created");
        return sComponent;
    }
}
```

The second trick is to use the holder to register the component **before** the fragment is even created. Then we launch the `TestActivity` with our `FragmentTestRule`. Now comes the third trick which is timing-dependent and does not always run correctly. **Directly** after launching the activity we get the `Fragment` instance by asking the `FragmentTestRule`. Then we swap the component, using the `TestFragmentComponentHolder` and inject the Fragment graph. The forth trick is we just wait for about 2 seconds for the Fragment to be created. And within the Fragment we make our component injection in `onViewCreated()`. Because then we don't inject the component to early because `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` are called before. So here is our `MainFragment`:

```
public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment implements MainView {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    @Inject
    MainPresenter mainPresenter;
    private View view;

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //((MainActivity)getActivity()).getComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(final String s) {
        mainPresenter.onClick(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getComponent().inject(this);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                MainFragment.this.onClick(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        mainPresenter.attachView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePerson(final Person person) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_greeting);
        textView.setText("Hello " + person.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mainPresenter.detachView();
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

And all the steps (second to forth trick) which I described before can be found in the `@Before` annotated `setUp()`-Method in this `MainFragmentTest` class:

```
public class MainFragmentTest implements
        InjectsComponent<TestFragmentComponent>, TestFragmentComponentHolder.ComponentCreator {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragmentTest";
    @Rule
    public FragmentTestRule<MainFragment> mFragmentTestRule = new FragmentTestRule<>(MainFragment.class);

    public AndroidApplication getApp() {
        return (AndroidApplication) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        TestFragmentComponentHolder.setCreator(this);

        mFragmentTestRule.launchActivity(null);

        MainFragment fragment = mFragmentTestRule.getFragment();

        if (!(fragment instanceof HasComponent) || !TestFragmentComponentHolder.hasComponentCreator()) {
            return;
        } else {
            ((HasComponent<FragmentComponent>) fragment).
                    setComponent(TestFragmentComponentHolder.getComponent(fragment));

            injectFragmentGraph();

            waitForFragment(R.id.fragmentContainer, 2000);
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws  Exception {
        TestFragmentComponentHolder.release();
        mFragmentTestRule = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void injectFragmentGraph() {
        ((InjectsComponent<TestFragmentComponent>) this).injectComponent(TestFragmentComponentHolder.getComponent());
    }

    protected Fragment waitForFragment(@IdRes int id, int timeout) {
        long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + timeout;
        while (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() <= endTime) {

            Fragment fragment = mFragmentTestRule.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id);
            if (fragment != null) {
                return fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public TestFragmentComponent createComponent(final Fragment fragment) {
        return DaggerTestFragmentComponent.builder()
                .testFragmentModule(new TestFragmentModule())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnClick_Fake() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.edittext)).perform(typeText("John"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.textview_greeting)).check(matches(withText(containsString("Hello Fake"))));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnClick_Real() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.edittext)).perform(typeText("John"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.textview_greeting)).check(matches(withText(containsString("Hello John"))));
    }


    @Override
    public void injectComponent(final TestFragmentComponent component) {
        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Except from the timing problem. This test runs in my environment in 10 of 10 test runs on an emulated Android with API Level 23. And it runs in 9 of 10 test runs on a real Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo device with Android 6.

As I wrote above you can download the whole example from [github](https://github.com/unlimited101/SwappingTestDoubles) and feel free to improve if you find a way to fix the little timing problem.

That's it!