# Dagger Field Injection Testing

Tags: android, mockito, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2 and have a few issues with generate singleton providers in the module when implementing tests for my class.

```
class SomeContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // this should be normal foo if run by application, 
    // or mocked foo if run by tests
    @Inject Foo foo;

    public Provider() {
        Component.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

@Module
class ProviderModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Foo providesFoo() {
        returns new Foo();
    }
}

@Module
class ProviderTestModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Foo providesFoo() {
        returns Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    }
}


public class SomeContentProviderTests extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    @Inject Foo foo; // this should be mocked Foo

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Component.getTestComponent().inject(this);
    }

    public void test1() {
        // needs new instance of Foo when test1 is run from SomeContentProvider
    }

    public void test2() {
        // needs another new instance of Foo when test2 is run from SomeContentProvider
    }
}
```

So I have 2 questions.

1. I cannot use constructor injection as `ContentProvider` has a default constructor. How does `SomeContentProvider` get the Foo from the the test module?
2. In `test1` and `test2`, how do I ensure that a new instance of `Foo` is created when each test is being run?

Thanks!

Comment: So right now my intent is to create another field of `Foo` and another constructor of `SomeContentProvider` that takes in a `Foo` just for testing purpose, after inject, if that field does exist, replace the injected `Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post especially useful for me. Though the particular problem I am have is much more convoluted - but I had used the same idea to mock the module's provider.

[How do you override a module/dependency in a unit test with Dagger 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939340/how-do-you-override-a-module-dependency-in-a-unit-test-with-dagger-2-0?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@Named` annotation for identify which dependency you want to inject if you have more than one dependency of same type.

See docs for more details: https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide#qualifiers

Comment: Im not sure if you understood my question correctly. Names qualifier would not be needed in my case.